# grep vs zgrep exit status differences with multiple files

Tags: grep, exit-status

Setup

```
echo "abc" >/tmp/foo1
echo "def" >/tmp/foo2
cp /tmp/foo1 /tmp/gzfoo1
cp /tmp/foo2 /tmp/gzfoo2
gzip /tmp/gzfoo*
```

grep exit status with multiple files and one match is 0

```
grep -q abc /tmp/foo[12]
echo $?
0
```

zgrep exit status with multiple unzipped files and one match is 1

```
zgrep -q abc /tmp/foo[12]
echo $?
1
```

zgrep exit status with multiple zipped files and one match is 1

```
zgrep -q abc /tmp/gzfoo[12].gz
echo $?
1
```

I do see that zgrep is a shell script.  And it does seem like if *any* grep returns non-zero, zgrep returns non-zero as well.  Here's my paraphrased excerpt from zgrep:

```
res=0
for input_file
do
  # ... run grep on input_file ...
  r=$?
  ...
  test $res -lt $r && res=$r
done
exit $res
```

zgrep version is (ancient) 1.3.12:

```
$ zgrep --version
zgrep (gzip) 1.3.12
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software.  You may redistribute copies of it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Jean-loup Gailly.
```

Also happens with zgrep (gzip) 1.6:

```
$ /<other_zgrep_path/bin/zgrep --version
zgrep (gzip) 1.6
Copyright (C) 2010-2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software.  You may redistribute copies of it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Jean-loup Gailly.

$ /<other_zgrep_path/bin/zgrep -q abc /tmp/gzfoo[12].gz
$ echo $? 
1
```

### Question:  Is there a bug in zgrep?  Should it be fixed?

Edit:  Found a newer machine with zgrep/gzip 1.8 and it doesn't have this problem.  So, it seems like my machine is just old.  Here's what it looks like on the newer machine:

```
: zgrep --version
zgrep (gzip) 1.8
Copyright (C) 2010-2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software.  You may redistribute copies of it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Jean-loup Gailly.

: zgrep -q abc /tmp/foo[12]
: echo $?
0
```

Hacky Workaround to avoid old/buggy zgrep:

```
: ( gzcat -f /tmp/foo[12] | grep -q abc ) >&/dev/null 
: echo $?
0
```

Comment: I can't reproduce with zgrep (gzip) 1.10. `zgrep -q abc /tmp/foo[12]` and `zgrep -q abc /tmp/gzfoo[12].gz` both return exit code 0. Please add the output of `zgrep --version` and `type zgrep` to your question.

Comment: I can confirm `zgrep (gzip) 1.9` (Debian buster) is good and `zgrep (gzip) 1.6` (Debian stretch) is bad.

Comment: There were a lot of changes from 1.6 to 1.7 regarding the exit code, see https://fossies.org/diffs/gzip/1.6_vs_1.7/zgrep.in-diff.html (variable `res=0` vs. `res=1` and the changes at the bottom of the page). Seems it was fixed there.

Comment: Thanks to l0b0 and Freddy for pointing to the correct solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get source code from
https://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=gzip. Return code was changed in
commit `d2a1928e5534017456dc8a3b600ba0b30cce4a6e`:

```
commit d2a1928e5534017456dc8a3b600ba0b30cce4a6e
Author: Paul Eggert <eggert@cs.ucla.edu>
Date:   Thu Jun 12 18:43:08 2014 -0700

    zgrep: exit with status 0 if a file matches and there's no trouble

    Reported by Pavel Raiskup in: http://bugs.gnu.org/17760
    * zgrep.in (res): Treat exit status 0 to be greater than 1.
    Also, exit immediately on software configuration error.
```

Commit message contains a link to bug report:
https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=17760

You can easily check it yourself. With `zgrep` built from the above
commit:

```
$ /media/data/gzip-install-newer/bin/zgrep --version
zgrep (gzip) 1.6.17-d2a1
Copyright (C) 2010-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software.  You may redistribute copies of it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Jean-loup Gailly.
$ /media/data/gzip-install-newer/bin/zgrep -q abc /tmp/foo[12]
$ echo $?
0
```

With `zgrep` built from the previous commit:

```
$ /media/data/gzip-install/bin/zgrep --version
zgrep (gzip) 1.6.16-ed8c
Copyright (C) 2010-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software.  You may redistribute copies of it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Jean-loup Gailly.
$ /media/data/gzip-install/bin/zgrep -q abc /tmp/foo[12]
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: Here's the [d2a1928e5534017456dc8a3b600ba0b30cce4a6e](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=gzip.git;a=commitdiff;h=d2a1928e5534017456dc8a3b600ba0b30cce4a6e;hp=ed8cd406121c3df501e94d14a6307b79594703c3;ds=sidebyside) diff.

Comment: Thanks for detailed reply!  Glad to see it's already fixed and just that I'm on an old version.